# zoom over vector in leaflet

Tags: polygon, leaflet, events, zoom

I have created a map from geojson file of administrative boundaries (polygons layer).

Similar to this [example](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson-example.html). When the mouse is over the polygon feature, the cursor changes from hand to finger. In the finger mode, map does not zoom on double click.

In my case, at higher zoom, whole map is made of adjacent polygon features so the mouse is always in the finger mode. I need to be able to zoom in on double click.

Comment: One possible solution to this problem can be to use your mousewheel to zoom in & out instead click.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either what @poshan has written, or add this line to `onEachFeature(feature, layer)`:

```
if( layer.options )
    layer.options.clickable = false;
```

Comment: This is good one, is there a workaround to open popup on click.

Comment: Well, you can add a listener: `layer.on('click', function() { layer.openPopup(); });`

Answer (score 4):

I think creating event on layers(polygon layers) will work.

```
layer_name.on('dblclick', function(e) {
a = map.getZoom();
map.setZoom(a + 1);})
```